# Data protection keys not persisted on newer OS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2019, data-protection

We have server provisioning and a CI/CD pipeline.
Some of our .Net Core services use [data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Services are now being migrated from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2019 with the same server settings and deployment pipeline, and now all of a sudden the following errors occur:

- *No XML encryptor configured. Key may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.*
- *Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.*
- *Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.*

I found a possible solution: [set Load User Profile, to True, in the app pool settings](https://cypressnorth.com/web-programming-and-development/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/).
But, we haven't done this on our Windows Server 2012 machines, so why should we on our Windows Server 2019 machines? And, is there a downside to loading the user profile?

Comment: I think this issue is from asp.net core not server itself or IIS. When the Data Protection system is initialized, it applies default settings based on the operational environment. So asp.net core will adjust this according to server environment.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Did you ever come up with an explanation for this one? I'm running into the same issue where I need to share the key among multiple applications, with everything pointing to a file share. On dev and test servers, golden. On a new staging server, no dice. Setting "load user profile" is also not a solution for my specific use case.

Comment: @EricTarasoff alas, haven't been able to fix it.